# how to get xslt output in a user control?

Tags: asp.net, .net

i have a xml and a xsl file. i want output of xsl in a user control and i've to pass some xslt arguments to my xsl also say

```
string m= "page1"
```

so this string should pass to xsl.

what i have in user control .cs file :

```
private readonly string XslFile = @"...\default.xslt";
private readonly string XmlFile = @"...\default.config";


private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string m = "page_1";


        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(XmlFile);

        XslTransform xsl = new XslTransform();
        xsl.Load(XslFile);

        XsltArgumentList xslarg = new XsltArgumentList();
        xslarg.AddParam("id", "", m);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        xsl.Transform(xdoc, xslarg, sw);

        string result = sw.ToString().Replace("&lt;","<").Replace("&gt;",">");

        sw.Close();

        label1.text= result; // i have this label in .ascx file

}
```

i have  in xsl file also. there is nothing wrong in xsl or xml file. i don't know where am i getting wrong. or any other approach , please tell me. i want this user control in so many pages, thats why i am using this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string result = sw.ToString();
string encodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(result);

...

label1.Text = encodedHtml;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) is the documentation.

Comment: is this the correct approach to use this label1.Text = encodedHtml; or should i use some other approach to print the output in usercontrol?